Umlauts in text added via a script in Photoshop
I'm adding text into a layer in Photoshop via a script like this:
var layerText;
var textItem;
layerText = activeDocument.artLayers.add();
layerText.kind = LayerKind.TEXT;
layerText.name = "choking hazard";

textItem = layerText.textItem;
textItem.contents = "Nicht geeignet für Kinder unter 3 Jahren.";
textItem.font = "Arial";
textItem.size = 50;
textItem.justification = Justification.LEFT;
textItem.color.rgb.hexValue = "000000";

...which comes out as:

If I do this manually via the text tool in Photoshop, I have no problem, my entire workspace is in German.
Do I need to specify anything else when adding the text via script?
Thanx in advance.

Works fine for me but i did note that the font didn't get set to Arial - you may need textItem.font = "ArialMT"; Is your script saved as UTF or another different encoded text format?

Looks like a character encoding mismatch. Check the script encoding is set to "UTF-8".
Also, try this:
var s = "Nicht geeignet für Kinder unter 3 Jahren."
s = decodeURIComponent(s);
textItem.contents = s;

